# Android wait() not working

Tags: android, multithreading, handler, wait

This is my first question here, so please forgive me if I disobeyed any of the forum rules.

I need my program to wait for 3 seconds and then change the Content View

My code is:

```
setContentView(R.layout.logout); 

new Thread(new Runnable() { 
    @Override 
    public void run(){ 
        try { 
           synchronized(this){ 
                wait(3000);
            } 
        } 
        catch(InterruptedException ex){                     
        }            
    } 
}).start();

setContentView(R.layout.main);
```

The program works with no errors, but there is no waiting. When it gets to this part, it just shows the "main" layout without showing the "logout" layout at all.

What is wrong in my approach?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As people noted, don't sleep on or otherwise block the UI thread, but you seem to be aware of this with the new thread you create.

**Now for why it doesn't behave as you want:**

Right now, you call `setContentView()`, start a new thread, call `setContentView()` a second time on the *UI thread* -- this happens in quick succession with no delay/wait/sleep inbetween. The `wait(3000)` happens in the new thread you started -- so *that new thread* starts, waits for 3000ms, then exits. It's an expensive no-op.

You would need to make the second call to `setContentView()` from *inside* that new thread's `run()` method to get the desired effect. Also, you should use `sleep()` instead of `wait()` -- `wait()` is a low-level tool for synchronizing threads while `sleep()` is the usual "don't continue for X amount of time".

**Let me propose a better way:**

An arguably nicer and much lighter approch is using [`Handler.postDelayed()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler.html#postDelayed%28java.lang.Runnable,%20long%29) -- this allows you to invoke a Runnable on the *UI thread* after a delay:

```
setContentView(R.layout.logout);
new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
    @Override
        public void run() {
            setContentView(R.layout.main);
        }
    }, 3000);
```

---

**Edit to reply to your comment:**

Define and find the button before the Runnable as a **final** variable, this way you can access it later from inside the Runnable.

Please note that to reference the `this` instance of the surrounding class from inside an anonymous inner class (your `new Runnable()`), you need to prefix it with the class name of the surrounding class (your `Activity` class):

```
final View submitButton = findViewById(R.id.submit_button); 
setContentView(R.layout.logout);
new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
    @Override
        public void run() {
            setContentView(R.layout.main);
            // adapt to your actual Activity class name:
            submitButton.setOnClickListener(YourClassName.this);
        }
    }, 3000);
```

Comment: thank you vm this works. 
But how can I add a listener when it returns to the "main" layout?
I mean I have a button and I want to add something like this:
View submitButton = findViewById(R.id.submit_button);
submitButton.setOnClickListener(this);
I cant do it inside the run method and if I do it after it I get an error

Comment: I did it.. I just called another method from run (set) where I sete the listeners. It works fine, I dont't know if i used good practices though (sorry, kind of new to android)

Comment: It's basically the same as passing in a final variable from outside the runnable -- in both cases the VM synthesizes some code to access the variable/method. That's fine. Choose what's the most readable to you :)

Comment: Your approach works fine too!
P.S: Thanks to all for the answers! I wanted to vote + in some of them, but it says "Vote Up requires 15 reputation"

Comment: Glad to help! It's great you want to upvote -- just wait till you got the necessary rep and then come back to your old questions to upvote/accept answers. Don't worry, people here will remind you of that if you forget ;)

Answer (score 5):

`wait()` doesn't wait for a certain amount of time, but rather has the current Thread wait for `this` to do a `notify()` for a maximum amount of time. What you are looking for, is `Thread.sleep()`.

And at the moment the only thing that will be waiting, is the additional thread you are spawning, not the activity itself. That's why I'd suggest you look at [`Handler.postDelayed()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler.html#postDelayed%28java.lang.Runnable,%20long%29), [`CountDownTimer`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/CountDownTimer.html) or [`AsyncTask`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html). Handling threads is very low-level.

Comment: +1 for the wait/sleep difference. Timer/AsyncTask are probably overkill (both performance and code-wise), `Handler.postDelayed()` seems to be the way to go.

Answer (score 3):

Your code not work to sleep UI thread.To sleep UI thread try this code

```
new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() 
{ 
    public void run() 
    { 
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
    }
}, 3000);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using Sleep() instead of Wait()

> android.os.SystemClock.sleep(3000)

Comment: don't sleep on the main event loop thread. This will make the app unresponsive.

Comment: Thnx for the answer. this works in terms of waiting but not in the way i wanted it:
     setContentView(R.layout.logout); 
     android.os.SystemClock.sleep(3000);
     setContentView(R.layout.main);
waits for 3 secs before showing the "main" layout indeed, but it doesnt show the "logout" layout

Answer (score 0):

As far as i can understand the wait is happening in the new thread where as you are calling setContentView(R.layout.main) in the current thread.

Try

```
setContentView(..)
synchronized(this) {
    this.wait(1000);
}
setContentView(..)
```

Please note sleeping or waiting in the UI thread is not a best practice though.

Comment: don't sleep (or wait) on the main event loop thread. This will make the app unresponsive.